# Can I manually install a windows service application using VS 2010 Express?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, service, installation, setup-project

I have created a Windows Service Application and attempted to install it using installutil. But it doesn't show up in my services list. After doing a lot of research I concluded this is because I do not have access to the Setup Project template VS2010 Professional provides. I only have VS2010 express.

I need to mimic any code and configuration for installing a Windows Service Application but without creating a Setup Project in VS 2010. I only have VS2010 Express and want to toy around with creating a service for my home PC.

In other words, is it even possible to hand code what a Setup Project template provides in VS 2010?

If so, what are the essential steps? Are there any tutorials available for how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the only thing you will need is a class which you will need to derive from ServiceBase and is instantiated from Program.cs.

Just compile and put your project output somewhere on your filesystem, open a command prompt and do InstallUtil your-assembly.exe.

Please note that you should use InstallUtil of .Net 4.0 (instead of 2.0).
On my PC, I use InstallUtil from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319